# How to Change Background color when uiview is animating

Tags: iphone

I use the following code, to animate to my UIView.

```
[UIView beginAnimations: @"hi"context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But when the UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft processes that time, the background will be displayed as white. I need to change that white place and i will add somecolor to that place.

The output is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved..

i used the following code to change that white color in delegate class as follows.

```
  -(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
// Override point for customization after app launch    
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window addSubview:navController.view];
[viewController displayScreen];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

UIColor* myColor = [UIColor blackColor];  // Or any other color you want.
[window setBackgroundColor:myColor];
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The backroundground maybe the view owned by navigationController or UIWindow. You can try to set those background color as your desired color.